# canvas command not working inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

Help! I am using python 3.5.2 and the function `self.new_game` is not working. It is supposed to put text on the canvas but it does nothing! There are also no errors that appear in the shell.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import os

WIDTH = 1920
HEIGHT = 1080
root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
planet_selected = 0
planet_name = "nothing"
planet_temp = -270
planet_size = 0.0
planet_life = 0.0

class Space(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        frame1 = Frame(self)
        self.canvas = Canvas(frame1, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT, bg ="white")
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.canvas.create_text(1920,1000,text='Planetary Creator',font=('Arial',15))
        self.master.title("Planetary Creator Alpha 0.1")
        frame = Frame(root, bg='grey', width=1920, height=40)
        frame.pack(fill='x')
        button1 = Button(frame, text='New Game',command=lambda : self.new_game())
        button1.pack(side='left', padx=10)
        button2 = Button(frame, text='Quit Game',command=lambda : os._exit(0))
        button2.pack(side='left')

#this function below does not work!!!

    def new_game(self):
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        size = self.canvas.create_text(960,540,text=str(planet_size) + "moon",font=("Arial",10))
        life = self.canvas.create_text(960,520,text="✣" + str(planet_life) + "%",font=("Arial",10))
        temp = self.canvas.create_text(960,500,text=str(planet_temp) + "°C",font=("Arial",10))
        name = self.canvas.create_text(960,480,text=planet_name,font=("Arial",15))

Space().mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't layout several widgets. You need to add `self.pack()`, `self.canvas.pack()`, and `frame1.pack()` to your `__init__` method.

Comment: where do I put self.pack()

Comment: all of those go in `Space.__init__`.

Comment: doing self.pack() makes my panel and buttons disappear

Comment: I usually want to call those layout managers from the parent, not sure if it@s the right way to do it though.

Comment: Yes, that's because you made your Canvas as large as the screen, so it pushes the buttons off the screen. make the canvas smaller.

Comment: @Nae I would agree, but the way OP starts the code in the last line prevents that.

Comment: packed the widgets, resized canvas but text still not appearing

Comment: I'll bet you made the canvas too small now. You are drawing text at 960, 580 so try a canvas size of  width = 1000, height = 600. I tested it so I know that works.

Comment: I made it width 1920, height 880 then changed and its still not working

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Drawing the wrong thing? Drawing the right thing in the wrong place? Throwing an error? Have you verified that the canvas is visible, and that the coordinates you are using are in the visible part of the canvas?

Comment: it means not happening at all and no error

Comment: I tested it and changed the bg value to "black" and it is not black. it is probably hidden. so how do I make it visible

Comment: but how do I show it I'm a python noob

Comment: The very first comment is telling you what is wrong. I suggest you start over, and start by just creating a `Space` frame that is empty but has a distinctive color. Make sure it's visible before you do anything else. Next, create `frame1` with a different color, and make sure it shows up. Then create the canvas and make sure it shows up. Solve one problem at a time.

Comment: wow thanks its working well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed `frame1` and put `Canvas` in `root` , and use `canvas.pack()` to see canvas in window.
(but I could use `self` instead of `root` and use `self.pack()` because `Space` inherits from `Frame`. it would ne more logical)

After that I had to only change text positions because windows was too big for my screen.

I used variables `CENTER_X`, `CENTER_Y` to put text in center regardless of the size of the screen.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import os

class Space(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master.title("Planetary Creator Alpha 0.1")

        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.focus_set()

        self.canvas.create_text(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, text='Planetary Creator', font=('Arial',15))

        frame = Frame(root, bg='grey', width=WIDTH, height=40)
        frame.pack(fill='x')

        button1 = Button(frame, text='New Game', command=self.new_game)
        button1.pack(side='left', padx=10)

        button2 = Button(frame, text='Quit Game', command=root.destroy)
        button2.pack(side='left')

    def new_game(self):
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)

        size = self.canvas.create_text(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, text=str(planet_size) + "moon", font=("Arial",10))
        life = self.canvas.create_text(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y-20, text="✣" + str(planet_life) + "%", font=("Arial",10))
        temp = self.canvas.create_text(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y-40, text=str(planet_temp) + "°C", font=("Arial",10))
        name = self.canvas.create_text(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y-60, text=planet_name, font=("Arial",15))

# --- main ---

WIDTH = 800 #1920
HEIGHT = 500 #1080

CENTER_X = WIDTH//2
CENTER_Y = HEIGHT//2

planet_selected = 0
planet_name = "nothing"
planet_temp = -270
planet_size = 0.0
planet_life = 0.0

root = Tk()
#root.state('zoomed')
Space(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you subclass Frame?

Comment: @Novel I kept original code but I was thinking about changing this. Finally I only wrote that I could use `self` instead of  `root`, etc because it would be more logical.